# Can entity variables be functions?

Tags: krl

Since functions and actions are first-class, is it possible for an entity variable to hold a function? Historically that was not the case; entity variables could only be flags, counters, trails, or literals.

A corollary to that, if the answer is true. Can a function be defined in a postlude and assigned directly to an entity variable?

(This is a question from the [CS 462 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/byu-cs-462-winter-2011/yMSDRkc5zYs/ZrQtiBOj0aoJ).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Entity variables can only contain strings and numbers, arrays, structs, and any combination of such.